# Validation.HasError attached property

Tags: wpf, mvvm, idataerrorinfo, caliburn

Did I miss something?

1- Style

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Validation.HasError}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="160" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 7 0 0"/>
    </Style>
```

2 - Viewmodel implement IDataErrorInfo
3- textBox in view

```
 <TextBox x:Name="FirstName" Text="{Binding Person.FirstName,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true}"></TextBox>
```

3 - I use Caliburn MVVM

I got " BindingExpression path error: 'Validation' property not found on 'object' ''PersonWindowViewModel' (HashCode=38783181)'. BindingExpression:Path=Validation.HasError; DataItem='PersonWindowViewModel' (HashCode=38783181); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='FirstName'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')"S

Answer (score 14):

Check out Beth Massi's article on implementing validation [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf.aspx)

Basically, you've used a `DataTrigger` where you just need a `Trigger`

So:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
        <Setter ... />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: I cannot tell you how many bloody times I have to come back here.

Comment: @Will - lol. I *love* WPF, but I really do think some of it could be a little simpler :)